# jqGrid-subgrid is not showing up

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

'm creating 2nd level subgrid. followed the example  (Sub Grid (2 nested levels)).
[jqgrid]http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx
when parent grid's row(+) symbol is clicked, It just shows one more empty row below It without column names, So I think, Its not even loading the subgrid on client. 
any ideas plz?
>

> **********aspx page:****************
>   < cc1:JQGrid ID="Jqgrid1" runat="server" OnDataRequesting="Jqgrid1_DataRequesting">
>   < SortSettings InitialSortColumn="" />
>   < Columns>
>   < cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="PrimaryId" PrimaryKey="True">
>   < /cc1:JQGridColumn>
>   < cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="ContractNumber">
>   < /cc1:JQGridColumn>
>   < cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="PONumber">
>   < /cc1:JQGridColumn>
>   < cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="POLineNumber">
>   < /cc1:JQGridColumn>
>   < cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="Description">
>   < /cc1:JQGridColumn>
>   < /Columns>
>   < ClientSideEvents SubGridRowExpanded="showSubGrid" />
>   < HierarchySettings HierarchyMode="Parent" />
>   < /cc1:JQGrid>
>   < /div>
>   < cc1:JQGrid ID="Jqgrid2" runat="server" OnDataRequesting="Jqgrid2_DataRequesting" >
>   < SortSettings InitialSortColumn="" />
>   < Columns>
>   < cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="BOMKEY" PrimaryKey="True" HeaderText="BKey">
>   < /cc1:JQGridColumn>
>   < cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="PARTNUMBER" HeaderText="Part#" >
>   < /cc1:JQGridColumn>
>   < cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Desc">
>   < /cc1:JQGridColumn>
>   < /Columns>
>   < HierarchySettings HierarchyMode="Child" />
>   < /cc1:JQGrid>
>   < script type="text/javascript">
>   function showSubGrid(subgrid_id, row_id)
>   {
>   showSubGrid_Jqgrid2(subgrid_id, row_id);
>   }
>
> ---
>
> ******code behind******
>       protected void Jqgrid1_DataRequesting(object sender,   > Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridDataRequestEventArgs e)
>       {
>       if (!LoadPurchaseOrderLineDataSet())
>       { return; }
>       Jqgrid1.DataSource = dtPurchaseOrderLine;
>       Jqgrid1.DataBind();
>       }
>       protected void Jqgrid2_DataRequesting(object sender,   Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridDataRequestEventArgs e)
>       {
>       LoadPurchaseOrderBOMDataSet(e.ParentRowKey);
>       Jqgrid2.DataSource = dsPurchaseOrderBOM;
>       Jqgrid2.DataBind();
>       }
>
> ---

Answer (score 1):

I found solution - "Primary key should not contain any special characters".